# How do I detect a datagridview starting to fill

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am looking for the cleanest way to see that a datagridview is in the process of being filled/repopulated. I will continue to look but I am not seeing an event yet that tells me this process is starting.

Thanks

Comment: what are you looking to do with the process of filling the data grid..? perhaps you could elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridView.DataSourceChanged`, `DataGridView.RowsAdded` and `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete list of DataGridView events:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4dwfh7x.aspx